# Can't compile .java file using javac on cmd

Tags: java, javac

I just started to learn Java programming. Following a guide/tutorial, I created my first .java file. The problem accrued when I tried to compile the .java file.

I have installed Java SE Development Kit 8u131. I have set the user Path variable to `C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin` but that didn't work.

The exact error I get when using javac command is the following: `'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Can you guys help me get the javac command working? I have no idea what the problem might be besides the Path variable.

[Picture of Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksWBJ.png)

Comment: Your path variable is wrong. Shouldn't there be a space between `Files` and `(x86)`? Regardless, it's definitely a path issue, so don't start imagining it's something else.

Comment: The point from @Kayaman is correct. Furthermore, the variables are reloaded after you logged out and logged in again. Maybe also after reboot, but I think the logout should do it

Comment: Turn out this was the problem, had no idea that might be the problem.

Comment: Since you guys here, do you know where the compiled .java files are stored?

Comment: if you are compiling java file from cmd, compiled files are stored on the same directory of java file.

Comment: If you mean the same location as the .java file then that didn't happen

Comment: can you post javac command you are trying with directory path?

Comment: The directory in which I am in is "C:\Users\Markus\Documents\Programming."

The command is "javac MyFirstProgram.java"

Comment: Not sure, `MyFirstProgram.class` file should be generated on your Programming folder

Comment: No file was generated

Comment: I can now compile the .java file but no files or executables are generated into the folder where my .java file is

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check that JDK is installed in which Directory (inside C drive of Windows OS), than follow these steps :

1. Goto "System Properties -> Environment Variables -> System variables"
2. Find a variable named as 'PATH' or 'Path' and click on Edit
3. Click New and write your JAVA path and click OK everywhere

   JAVA paths :

   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin (for 64-bit OS)

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin (for 32-bit OS)

Comment: Hmh. Warning: The javah tool is planned to be removed in the next major
JDK release. The tool has been superseded by the '-h' option added
to javac in JDK 8. Users are recommended to migrate to using the
javac '-h' option; see the javac man page for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should quote your path, because it contains a space:

[Should environment variables that contain a executable-path with spaces also contain the necessary quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730429/should-environment-variables-that-contain-a-executable-path-with-spaces-also-con)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a JAVA_HOME variable in 'User variables' section which points to the jdk folder (not bin folder), i.e. set the value to

> C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131

The you should edit the 'Path' variable in 'System variables' and add the path that points to the bin directory of the jdk folder, which you have already done.

Path varaible should have the following entry:

> C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin

Also, just make sure you have an entry that points to the command propmt inside Path varaible, these are stored by default, but in case you have messed with them

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\"Version folder goes here"\

Or

> C:\Windows\System32\

Now you should be able to compile and run successfully.

Answer (score -1):

You need to verify java_home variable by `echo %JAVA_HOME%` command and install this variable if not present to `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`
or `C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.8.0_131` when your java installation in (x86) folder. After that verify your installation by `java -version` command

Comment: What is that for?

Comment: First you need to verify java installation by java -version, if it not installed make steps specified in my answer

Comment: @MarkusKuusmann Yeah,first check java is installed in you machine.

Comment: It is. And now I can compile my .java file but I know there should be some files generated, which is not happening

Comment: I also set the JAVA_HOME