# Can't run a java file using javac

Tags: java, cmd, javac

I've got the same problem as the user who posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844006/cant-compile-java-file-using-javac-on-cmd). I am trying to run a Java file on a Windows machine using Command Prompt, but I'm having no success using any of the information I've gleaned from the linked question, nor from [WikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-the-Java-Software-Development-Kit#/Image:Install-the-Java-Software-Development-Kit-Step-28-Version-2.jpg), nor from [this user on another site](https://www.edureka.co/community/4800/unable-resolve-error-recognized-internal-external-command) with the same problem.

Here are the steps I've taken.

1. I've created a Java file using Notepad, called `HelloWorld.java`, and saved it in a folder called "Java". The file directory is `C:\Users\[myname]\Google Drive\Java`. The code in the file is a simple Hello World as below:

   ```
   class HelloWorld {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println("Hello World!");
       }
   }
   ```
2. I've downloaded Java version 8, and the latest version of the Java JDK (14.0.1) from the website. I previously had the JDK 12.x.x installed, so I uninstalled that.
3. I've opened System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables, gone to the "Path" variable in "System variables", clicked "Edit" and added a new environment variable, which was the path to the JDK bin: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin`. I then clicked "Move Up" until this variable was at the top.
4. After clicking OK and closing this window, I've opened Command Prompt, typed `set path=C:\Users\[myname]\Google Drive\Java` in order to (I imagine) set the path to where my `HelloWorld.java` file is. I've typed in `path` to confirm that this has worked.
5. I've typed in Command Prompt `javac HelloWorld.java`. When I hit Enter, I get the output:

   ```
   'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file.
   ```

I'm honestly not sure what steps are left to take. Is there a simple fix to get this file to run?

Comment: Step 4 undoes step 3.

Comment: In step 4, use `cd` command to get to the directory where your java file is located.

Comment: In Step 4 : Don;t set the PATH again. Simply do a cd <your-java-file-path> and execute step 5

Comment: Thanks @AlexRudenko and Som, in addition to the accepted answer I've succeeded in running the program from CMD due to your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps

1. Setup the environment variables properly. In the `Path` System variable, you should add the path to bin directory. Something like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.5\bin` and then, you need to define a new system variable with name `JAVA_HOME` and point it to the java installation directory, not the bin directory. Something like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.5`
2. You need NOT use the `Set` command, as of now environment variables are set. Open up a new powershell or command prompt and type `java -version`. If this prints the java version, then you are good to go with the next steps.
3. Go to your directory where your java class resides. Open up a powershell window there, with `shift + right click` and `open Powershell window here` option. Then type `javac HelloWorld.java`
4. To run programme, `java HelloWorld`

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you for the clear steps, I've now successfully run the program both from the powershell (which I didn't know existed!) and from the Command Prompt using @AlexRudenko's advice.