# Extra quotes for path with the spaces

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to execute command from Windows CMD

```
cmd /c "timeout 3 > nul & start /min C:\Users\Me\Documents\Path with extra spaces\myapp.exe"
```

Since path contain spaces I would need to place quotes around it in order to specify correct location. I have tried number of ways so far(extra double quotes "", escapes ^), non of them worked yet. Like this:

```
cmd /c "timeout 3 > nul & start /min """C:\Users\Me\Documents\Path with extra spaces\myapp.exe""""
```

Command have to be run exactly from CMD.

Comment: [\[ This \]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851012/set-a-path-variable-with-spaces-in-the-path-in-a-windows-cmd-file-or-batch-file) might help..

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/355988 (hint: Use /S)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`start` takes the first quoted parameter as a windows title. So give it a dummy title (for example an empty string `""`):

```
cmd /c "timeout 3 > nul & start "" /min "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Path with extra spaces\myapp.exe""
```