# copy function returns The system cannot find the file specified, when the file exists

Tags: cmd

```
copy C:\Users\MinCarve\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\PROGRAM\Debug\PROGRAM.exe 
     C:\Users
```

returns

> The system cannot find the file specified. when the executable
>   **exists** in that directory!

Comment: Probably need quotes around the file name.

Comment: how do i add quotes to the directory, if it is a variable in c++?

Comment: Related: [Set a path variable with spaces in the path in a Windows .cmd file or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1851012)

Comment: after an hour of digging, i finally did it!                                                                                     
 `string _Loc(Loc);
 string __Loc = "\"" + _Loc + "\"";

 system(("copy " + __Loc + " \"C:\\Windows\System32\"").c_str());`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The path of your file has a space in its name, which means you have to surround the path which contains spaces with quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

```
copy C:\Users\MinCarve\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\PROGRAM\Debug\PROGRAM.exe C:\Users
```

has FOUR parameters. It tries to copy
`C:\Users\MinCarve\documents\visual` (which does (probably) not exist) to the location
`studio` (which (probably) doesn't exist too, and two more parameters:
`2017\Projects\PROGRAM\Debug\PROGRAM.exe`
`C:\Users`

`Copy` stops with the first error found, in this case, `C:\Users\MinCarve\documents\visual` does not exist.

**Solution:** quote parameters that contain one or more spaces. Best practice: do it anyway: `copy "source" "destination"`.

```
copy "C:\Users\MinCarve\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\PROGRAM\Debug\PROGRAM.exe" "C:\Users\"
```

Comment: @Kirsten: is that the explanation you are looking for, or do you need anything more?

Comment: Thanks @Stephan. I think my problem may be something to do with the vm being on a Linux box. I may need to ask a separate question. As a work around I just got rid of the spaces.

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference whether Win runs on a physical or virtual machine.

Comment: I think it might be a permissions thing. I was able to run a similar command as administrator. I was copying to a subfolder of C:\Program Files (x86)

Comment: yes, that folder tree needs Admin rights to write to.